# how ot use (in_array)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using ‘  ‘to pass my array value  from one page to another. I have an array value that is doesn’t have value always. How to put condition when it have value pass it but I don’t have idea about (in array) in  .

this is my passing code

```
echo '<td ><a href="sessiondetails.php?'.htmlentities(http_build_query(array('docname'=>$key['DocName'],'HosName'=>$key['HosName'],'DoctorNotes',['DoctorNotes'])),ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED,'UTF-8',true).'">More>></a></font></td></tr>';
```

this is get query

```
$DoctorNotes=$_GET ['DoctorNotes'];[enter image description here][1]
```

here is my result array

error msg
' Array to string conversion in.....'

Answer (score 2):

**in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array**

```
<?php
$names = array("VYSAKH", "DODESTINO", "CHOORAKKATT", "VYSU");
if (in_array("DODESTINO", $names)) {
    echo "Got DODESTINO";
}
if (in_array("VYSU", $names)) {
    echo "Got VYSU";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in_array()` function searches an array for a specific value.

Note: If the search parameter is a string and the type parameter is set to TRUE, the search is case-sensitive.

> Syntax
>
> in_array(search,array,type)

```
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

if (in_array("Glenn", $people))
{
    echo "Match found";
}
else
{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp)**